# Ruby on Rails Ошибка при попытке создания пользователя

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Суть ошибки такова есть action для создания новго пользователя

```
def new
@user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:login, :email, assword, assword_confirmation))
if @user.save
redirect_to @user
else
render 'new'
end
end
```

И есть форма с которой отправляются данные для создания

```
<% provide(:title, 'Создание нового пользователя') %> 
  <h1>Регистрация</h1> 
  <div class="center header"> 
    <div class="contacts-block-line"> 
      <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %> 
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %> 
        <%= f.hidden_field :save, value: 1 %> 
        <%= f.label :login %> <%= f.text_field :login, class: "callback" %>
        <%= f.label :email %> <%= f.text_field :email, class: "callback" %>
        <%= f.label assword %> <%= f.password_field assword, class: "callback" %>
        <%= f.label assword_confirmation, "Confirmation" %> 
        <%= f.password_field assword_confirmation, class: "callback" %>
        <div class="btn-large"> 
          <%= f.submit "Create my account" %> 
        </div> 
     <% end %> 
   </div> 
  </div>
```

При попытке зайти на страницу по ссылке выдает ошибку

```
param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

При этом не работает только заход по ссылке. Просто раньше было условие без permit и оно заходило на эту страницу, но не сохраняло. Так вот если я уже нахожусь на этой страницу и просто обновляю ее, с новым условием в actione, то все работает.

Подскажите, мб надо сделать проврку через hidden_field на первый заход на страницу с формой? И если такое возможно, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Решил данный конфликт добавив

```
params.fetch(:user, Hash.new).permit(:login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```